# Is it possible to get 'Real Time Comments' using 'Facebook Webhooks' for a specific post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, webhooks

I have setup my app in Laravel to use Facebook's Graph API.
I have all the required permissions to manage a page and also have page access token.
Here is the scenario :
I have subscribed the Webhooks for 'feed' of the page, it sends a json object on callback url for every change that happens on page.
Question:
Is it possible to have Webhooks for a particular post? I have post id, and I want to get real time comments of that post? Is it possible with Facebook's Graph API Webhooks?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can only subscribe to the fields/edges listed in the documentation.

Comment: Another problem i am facing right now with webhooks is, Post id is converted to floating points in webhook response, like this : 2.6638303712428E+14, any thoughts?

Comment: That is just a matter of how you handle what the webhook sends you. Since you tagged this PHP, I assume json_decode comes into play somewhere - go check the manual on that, there’s a flag to have big integer values parsed into strings.